# A Definite Integral Whose Value Will Be Familiar To Everyone?

Tags: calculus

Here's a definite integral whose value carries memories of grade school. Is there a useful generalization ?

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2} \ dx = \frac{22}{7} - \pi$$

Comment: [Indeed, there is.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_22/7_exceeds_π)

Comment: [Is there an integral that proves $\pi > 333/106$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1956/264)

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079024/expression-for-int-01-xn1-xn-1x2-dx

Answer (score 4):

On 28 November 2003 I created [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_22/7_exceeds_%CF%80), to which various others have contributed since then.  I think I was the one who added some generalizations, but I'm not sure.

Comment: (I'm looking for an integral that evaluates to 355/113 - pi)

Comment: I'm not sure that would be difficult to do, but if you want it to be something that can be seen to be positive without knowing in advance that $355/113>\pi$, that may be harder.  For example, certainly $\displaystyle\int_0^1\left(\frac{355}{113}-\pi\right)\,dx$ $=\dfrac{355}{113}-\pi$, but probably that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: You aren't far off,I thought it would be nice to have an arctangent to evaluate. Reference: "Integral proofs that 355/113 > pi" Stephen K. Lucas

Answer (score 1):

Here are seven series and integrals for the first four convergents to $\pi$ and a question to find the missing one.

[Series and integrals for inequalities and approximations to $\pi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1654104/series-and-integrals-for-inequalities-and-approximations-to-pi)

A generalization is given by
$$\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{240}{(4k+1)(4k+2)(4k+3)(4k+5)(4k+6)(4k+7)}=\int_0^1 \frac{x^{4n}(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}dx$$

which allows to compute sequentially closer rational approximations to $\pi$ by adding the terms of the series.