# Expression for $\int_0^1 x^n(1-x)^{n}/(1+x^2) \ dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

An answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078923/a-calculation-that-goes-awfully-wrong-if-we-let-pi-22-7/1078929) makes clever use of an integral of this form:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^n(1-x)^n}{1+x^2} dx$$

Is there a closed form for this for arbitrary positive integer $n$?

(I expect this question has been asked before, but I couldn't find it. So perfectly happy if you can find it and close this question out.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Warning: incoming eyesore.

### Introduction

Using the binomial theorem,

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n (1 - x)^n}{1 + x^2}\,\text{d}x &= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n}{1+x^2}\sum_{m = 0}^{n} {n \choose m}(-1)^{m}x^m\,\text{d}x \\
&= \sum_{m = 0}^{n} {n \choose m}(-1)^{m}  \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{n+m}}{1+x^2} \,\text{d}x
\end{align*}

Suppose first that $n + m = 2q$ for some $q$ then

$$
\frac{x^{2q}}{1+x^2} = \frac{(-1)^{q}}{1 + x^2} - \sum_{\ell = 0}^{q - 1}(-1)^{\ell + q}x^{2\ell}
$$

Therefore,

$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{2q}}{1+x^2} = (-1)^{q}\frac{\pi}{4} - \sum_{\ell = 0}^{q - 1} \frac{(-1)^{\ell + q}}{2\ell + 1}
$$

Now suppose that $n + m = 2p + 1$ for some $p$ then

$$
\frac{x^{2p + 1}}{1+x^2} = \frac{(-1)^{p}x}{1 + x^2} - \sum_{\ell = 0}^{p - 1}(-1)^{\ell + p}x^{2\ell + 1}
$$

Therefore,

$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{2p + 1}}{1+x^2} \,\text{d}x =\frac{(-1)^{p}}{2}\ln(2) - \sum_{\ell = 0}^{p - 1} \frac{(-1)^{\ell + p}}{2\ell + 2}  
$$

### Case: $n$ even

If $n$ is even then write $n = 2n'$ and then

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{2n'} (1 - x)^{2n'}}{1 + x^2}\,\text{d}x &= \sum_{m = 0}^{2n'} {2n' \choose m}(-1)^{m}  \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{2n'+m}}{1+x^2} \,\text{d}x \\
&=  \sum_{m = 0}^{n'} {2n' \choose 2m} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{2(n'+m)}}{1+x^2} \,\text{d}x \\
&- \sum_{m = 0}^{n' - 1} {2n' \choose 2m + 1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{2(n'+m) + 1}}{1+x^2} \,\text{d}x 
\end{align*}

Use the previous results

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{2n'} (1 - x)^{2n'}}{1 + x^2}\,\text{d}x &= \sum_{m = 0}^{n'} {2n' \choose 2m}\left[(-1)^{n' + m}\frac{\pi}{4} - \sum_{\ell = 0}^{n' + m - 1} \frac{(-1)^{\ell + n' + m}}{2\ell + 1} \right] \\
&- \sum_{m = 0}^{n' - 1} {2n' \choose 2m + 1} \left[ \frac{(-1)^{n' + m}}{2}\ln(2) - \sum_{\ell = 0}^{n' + m - 1} \frac{(-1)^{\ell + n' + m}}{2\ell + 2} \right]
\end{align*}

### Case: $n$ odd

If $n$ is odd then write $n = 2n' + 1$ and then

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{2n' + 1} (1 - x)^{2n' + 1}}{1 + x^2}\,\text{d}x &= \sum_{m = 0}^{2n' + 1} {2n' + 1 \choose m}(-1)^{m}  \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{2n'+m + 1}}{1+x^2} \,\text{d}x \\
&=  \sum_{m = 0}^{n'} {2n' + 1\choose 2m} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{2(n'+m) + 1}}{1+x^2} \,\text{d}x \\
&- \sum_{m = 0}^{n'} {2n' + 1 \choose 2m + 1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{2(n'+m + 1)}}{1+x^2} \,\text{d}x 
\end{align*}

Again, using the previous results,

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{2n' + 1} (1 - x)^{2n' + 1}}{1 + x^2}\,\text{d}x &= \sum_{m = 0}^{n'} {2n' + 1 \choose 2m}\left[\frac{(-1)^{n' + m}}{2}\ln(2) - \sum_{\ell = 0}^{n' + m - 1} \frac{(-1)^{\ell + n' + m}}{2\ell + 2} \right] \\
&- \sum_{m = 0}^{n' - 1} {2n' + 1 \choose 2m + 1} \left[ (-1)^{n' + m + 1}\frac{\pi}{4} - \sum_{\ell = 0}^{n' + m} \frac{(-1)^{\ell + n' + m + 1}}{2\ell + 1} \right]
\end{align*}

Those sums are all finite, so in principle that's the solution. I can't immediately see how to simplify it though.

Comment: (Good thing you warned about eyesore, otherwise that "in principal" instead of "in principle" would have been painful...) ;-)

Comment: @HansLundmark Haha, that's embarrassing. Now it's an $[\text{eyesore} -\epsilon]$ :)

Comment: I like this answer as the sums only have a finite number of terms. Thanks for writing it out.

Comment: @SimonS No problem :)

Answer (score 10):

Can I get a quarter of an upvote for finding [the formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_22/7_exceeds_%CF%80#Extensions) for every positive integer divisible by 4?

$$\frac{1}{2^{2n-2}}\int_0^1 \frac{x^{4n}(1-x)^{4n}}{1+x^2}dx = \\ \sum_{j=0}^{2n-1}\frac{(-1)^j}{2^{2n-j-2}(8n-j-1){8n - j - 2 \choose 4n + j}} + (-1)^n\left(\pi - 4 \sum_{j=0}^{3n-1}\frac{(-1)^j}{2j+1}\right)$$

The original question links to a question posed on the 1968 Putnam Competition.  For $4n=4$ the value of the integral is $(22/7) - \pi$.  Larger values of $4n$ lead to better approximations of $\pi$ expressed as ratios of smallish positive integers.

Comment: You got four quarters ! Cheers

Comment: It looks like magic to me, but that means you probably deserve a quarter upvote. But I gave you four, just to be sure.

Answer (score 9):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

> With $\ds{0 < z < 1}$:

\begin{align}&\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}z^{n}
\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n}\pars{1 - x}^{n} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x
=\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over 1 + x^{2}}\,{1 \over 1 - zx\pars{1 - x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm]&={1 \over z}\int_{0}^{1}
{\dd x \over \pars{1 + x^{2}}\pars{x^{2} - x + z^{-1}}}
\\[5mm]&={8\root{z}\pars{3z - 2}\,{\rm arccsc}\pars{2/\root{z}}
-\root{4 - z}\braces{\bracks{\pi - 2\ln\pars{2}}z - \pi} \over 4\root{4 - z}\pars{2z^{2} - 2z + 1}}
\end{align}

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n}\pars{1 - x}^{n} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x}
> \\[5mm]&=\bracks{z^{n}}\pars{{8\root{z}\pars{3z - 2}\,{\rm arccsc}\pars{2/\root{z}}
> -\root{4 - z}\braces{\bracks{\pi - 2\ln\pars{2}}z - \pi} \over 4\root{4 - z}\pars{2z^{2} - 2z + 1}}}
> \end{align}

Comment: It took quite a bit of staring to see what you did on the first line, but I finally did (geometric series).  Very clever.  But once you have the integral (on the third line), what lets you recover the integral for a particular $n$?

Comment: In addition to what @John said, how come the result depends on $z$?

Comment: @Mr.G: notation: $[z^n](f(z))$ is the coefficient of $z^n$ in the series expansion of $f(z)$. This means that what Felix has provided is a [Generating Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) for the sequence of values depending on $n$.

Answer (score 4):

By using the Euler Beta function:
$$
I = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n(1-x)^n}{1+x^2} \, dx 
= \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} (-1)^k \int_{0}^{1} x^{n+2k}(1-x)^n \, dx
$$

$$
= \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} (-1)^k \frac{\Gamma(n+2k+1)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(2n+2k+2)}
=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2n+2k+1)\binom{2n+2k}{n}}.
$$

Comment: Incredibly clever!