# History Behind Integral Error Between $\pi$ and $22/7$

Tags: definite-integrals, math-history, pi

Looking at an expression for $\pi$

$$\pi = \frac{22}7-\int_0^1 \frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2} \ dx$$

it seems to me that the integral expression is the error between the approximation $\frac{22}7$ and $\pi$. Is there any history behind the discovery of this integral? Was it tied to the error between the two numbers or was it discovered separately and only later applied?

Comment: Related (but not the answer to this exact question): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079024/expression-for-int-01-xn1-xn-1x2-dx

I guess someone playing around with integrals of this form stumbled on this relationshihp.

Comment: I think it was on the 1968 Putnam exam, so it's older than that. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_22/7_exceeds_%CF%80) is a Wikipedia article about this equality. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for the Wikipedia article but it doesn't really explain where the integral as the exact error came from.

Answer (score 0):

This is the earliest instance of the formula that I could find.

http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/19/75_Part_3/133

J. London Math. Soc. (1944) 19 (75 Part 3): 133-134.
doi: 10.1112/jlms/19.75_Part_3.133

Perhaps this is where it was first discovered.

Comment: I can't access it; could you upload a picture or whatever is in the document please?