# Calculus Question: $\int_0^1\frac{(x-x^2)^4}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have no idea how to find this integral:

$$\int_0^1\frac{(x-x^2)^4}{1+x^2}\ dx\ ?$$

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a well known integral because of the startling punch line that you see only when you've finished evaluating it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_22/7_exceeds_%CF%80

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you very much. I didn't know that.

Comment: Here's a related [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956/is-there-an-integral-that-proves-pi-333-106)

Comment: A post about this integral on MO: [Source and context of $\frac{22}{7} - \pi = \int_0^1 (x-x^2)^4 dx/(1+x^2)$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/67384).

Comment: See also: [Evaluating $\int_0^1 \frac{x^4 (1-x)^4}{1+x^2} dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2084526)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT :**
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{(x-x^2)^4}{1+x^2}\ dx&=\int_0^1\frac{x^4-4x^5+6x^6-4x^7+x^8}{1+x^2}\ dx\tag1\\
&=\int_0^1\left(x^6-4x^5+5x^4-4x^2+4-\frac4{1+x^2}\right)\ dx.\tag2\\
\end{align}
$$
See [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) for $(1)$ and [polynomial long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) for $(2)$. Also
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac1{1+x^2}\ dx=\frac\pi4
\end{align}
$$
by letting $x=\tan\theta$. The answer is $\ \color{blue}{\dfrac{22}7-\pi}$.

Comment: it reads as if the answer is $\pi/4$. Perhaps you should clarify it for the OP (getting rid of the equal sign in front of the integral on the last line.

Comment: @ChrisK Fix it. Thanks. :)

Comment: You're welcome @Venus. :)