# Evaluating $\int_0^1 \frac{x^4 (1-x)^4}{1+x^2} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

We have to solve the following  $$\int_0^1 \frac{x^4 (1-x)^4}{1+x^2} dx$$

I tried to substitute $x =\tan m$, but in that I got stuck.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_22/7_exceeds_%CF%80#Details_of_evaluation_of_the_integral

Comment: This seems to be rather popular integral: [Finding $\int_0^1{\frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}}dx$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/129625),
[Shortest method for $\int^{1}_{0}\frac{x^{4}\left(1-x\right)^{4}}{1+x^{2}}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1450910),
[Creative way for $\int _0 ^1 \frac{x^4 (1-x)^4} {x^2 +1} {\rm d}x$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1614676).
Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint_0%5E1%20%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E4%20(1-x)%5E4%7D%7B1%2Bx%5E2%7D%20dx%24&p=1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint -

Simplify term by multiplying $x^4(1-x)^2(1-x)^2$ then divide by $1+x^2$. Then easily integrate it.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

No substitution required here: just divide $x^4(1-x)^4$ by $x^2+1$.

Comment: Sir it is $(1-x)^4$.

Comment: Oops! I misread the formula. Fixed. Thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 4):

Apply long division on the integrand to obtain
$$\int_0^1 \left(x^6 - 4x^5 + 5x^4 - 4x^2 + 4  - \frac{4}{1+x^2}\right)dx,$$
which is easy to solve.

Comment: reduces to $\frac{22}{7}-\pi.$