# Proof that $\frac{2}{3} < \log(2) < \frac{7}{10}$

Tags: inequality, logarithms, approximation, alternative-proof, pi

Positive integrals
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2x(1-x)^2}{1+x^2}dx=\pi-3$$
and 
$$\int_0^1\frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{22}{7}-\pi
$$
(https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1618454/134791)

prove that $$3<\pi<\frac{22}{7}$$

Is there a similar argument for the following $\log (2)$ inequality?
$$\frac{2}{3}<\log(2)<\frac{7}{10}$$

Comment: I was just searching my books for a proof that the value of pi we learn in school is slightly greater than pi. So, I'm glad I found this question !

Comment: @user230452 You may find that proof here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_22/7_exceeds_%CF%80

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are positive integrals that relate $\log(2)$ to its first four convergents: $0,1,\frac{2}{3},\frac{7}{10}$.
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{2x}{1+x^2}dx
&=
\log\left(2\right) \\
\int_0^1\frac{(1-x)^2}{1+x^2}dx
&=
1-\log\left(2\right) \\
\int_0^1\frac{x^2(1-x)^2}{1+x^2}dx
&=
\log\left(2\right)-\frac{2}{3} \\
\int_0^1\frac{x^4(1-x)^2}{1+x^2}dx
&=\frac{7}{10}-\log\left(2\right) \\
\end{align}
$$

Therefore,
$$-\int_0^1\frac{x^2(1-x)^2}{1+x^2}dx<0<\int_0^1\frac{x^4(1-x)^2}{1+x^2}dx$$

$$\frac{2}{3}-\log(2)<0<\frac{7}{10}-\log\left(2\right)$$

$$\frac{2}{3}<\log(2)<\frac{7}{10}$$

A similar set is available with denominators $(1+x)$:

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x}dx
&= 
\log(2) \\
\int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+x}dx
&=
1-\log(2)\\
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{x^2(1-x)}{1+x} dx 
&= 
\log(2)-\frac{2}{3} \\ 
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{x^5(1-x)}{1+x} dx
&= 
\frac{7}{10}-\log(2)
\end{align}$$

and series versions are given by

$$\begin{align}
\log(2)-\frac{2}{3}
&=
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k+1)(2k+2)(2k+3)} \\
\frac{7}{10}-\log(2)
&=
\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k+2)(2k+3)(2k+4)} \\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: You answered your own question ?

Comment: Do you mind explaining the first four steps ?

Comment: @user230452
Yes, I answered it, I read somewhere that this is OK.
For the first one, you may change variable $t=(1+x^2)$ so $2xdx=dt$ and then use $\int\frac{dt}{t}=log(t)$. For the others, the process is parallel to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_22/7_exceeds_%CF%80#Details_of_evaluation_of_the_integral

Comment: @user230452 You also have the third one in detail here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Proof_that_22/7_exceeds_%CF%80#Proof_that_natural_log_.282.29_exceeds_2.2F3

Comment: You posted an answer at nearly the exact same time as you posted the question?

Comment: @Daniel http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @qwr That's the "somewhere" I didn't manage to find when answering to user230452... thank you!

Comment: How do you get the hunch when faced with an inequality in between log2 and two rational numbers to start the approach from integral calculus ?

Comment: @user230452 hint: write the answer first and then the question.

Comment: Write the answer first and then the question ?

Comment: @user230452 The exponents in 
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1+x%5E4(1-x)%5E4dx%2F(1%2Bx%5E2) may be changed
to find rational approximations to $log(2)$ and $\pi$.

Comment: That link to blog.stackoverflow does not grant a blanket  permission to ask questions with precomposed answers. At least that's how it is applied in Math.SE. This was discussed - heatedly I may add - when one user was systematically doing this and used that same blog post as an excuse. So my advice is to tread carefully. Also read [this meta thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4680/11619) and the previous discussions linked to there. **If anyone wants to discuss this further, don't do it here, but take it to relevant meta threads instead.**

Comment: @user230452 The seventh integral is evaluated here to prove that $\frac{7}{12}<\log(2)<\frac{5}{6}$
http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1648329/134791