# A magnificent series for $\pi-333/106$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, pi, constants

> Stated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1593090/583016) without proof is the magnificent series $$\frac{48}{371} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{118720 k^2+762311 k+1409424}{(4 k+9) (4 k+11) (4 k+13) (4 k+15) (4 k+17) (4 k+19) (4 k+21) (4 k+23)} \\=\pi-\frac{333}{106},$$ which proves that $\pi>333/106$.

I can only assume that the series is proven using the integral $$\pi-\frac{333}{106}=\frac{1}{530}\int_0^1 \frac{x^5(1-x)^6(197+462x^2)}{1+x^2}dx.$$My attempts have been so far to split up the integral as
$$\begin{align}
530J&=\int_0^1 \frac{x^5(1-x)^6(197+462x^2)}{1+x^2}dx\\
&=197\int_0^1 \frac{x^5(1-x)^6}{1+x^2}dx+462\int_0^1\frac{x^{7}(1-x)^6}{1+x^2}dx\\
&=197J_1+462J_2.
\end{align}$$
Each remaining integral is turned into a series with 
$$\frac1{1+x^2}=\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^n x^{2n}$$
so we have two series of the form
$$f(p)=\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^n\int_0^1 x^{p+2n}(1-x)^6dx=720\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^n\frac{(p+2n)!}{(p+2n+7)!}.$$
Each factorial term is rewritten as $$\frac{s!}{(s+7)!}=\frac1{(s+1)(s+2)(s+3)(s+4)(s+5)(s+6)(s+7)},$$
so that 
$$f(p)=720\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^n}{\prod_{k=1}^{7}(2n+p+k)}.$$
Then $$J_1=f(5)\\ J_2=f(7).$$
But how does one get from $530J=197f(5)+462f(7)$ to the series in question? Furthermore, how do we prove that $J=\pi-333/106$? I would assume that one would at some point use the binomial theorem then be left with a bunch of integrals like $$\int_0^1\frac{x^qdx}{1+x^2}$$ which I suppose are evaluable in terms of $\pi$, but it seems like a great deal of cancellation/simplification would have to occur and I do not immediately see where this would happen. There has to be an easier way.

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting post, for sure. I do not see how $$\int_0^1\frac{x^qdx}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{4} \left(\psi\left(\frac{q+3}{4}\right)-\psi
   \left(\frac{q+1}{4}\right)\right)$$ could be  are evaluated in terms of $\pi$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Use the [digamma reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Reflection_formula).

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt. Shame on me ! I forgot this one.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt how may we use the digamma reflection to simplify $$\psi_0(\tfrac{q+3}{4})-\psi_0(\tfrac{q+1}{4})?$$ this is of the form $$\psi_0(s+\tfrac12)-\psi_0(s)...$$

Comment: @clathratus You can reduce it using the recurrence relation (i.e. polynomial long division) to $\psi(3/4)-\psi(1/4)$, to which you can apply the reflection formula (i.e. solving $\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm dx}{1+x^2}$ and $\int_0^1\frac{x~\mathrm dx}{1+x^2}$).

Comment: @clathratus How do you get enough sleep if you are a high school student and also constantly looking at series like this one ? 

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch the only way I can think to answer that is by admitting that I am a massive nerd who does not get enough sleep. I think I would get even less sleep though if I were two years younger and in a university ;)

Comment: @clathratus Well, for me at least, high school was more stressful than university... Now, I have all my time to focus on maths 

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Probably not a very elegant method, as it makes a great use of a CAS. However it seems quite general for this kind of series. Inversely, it can be used to create similar results.

The terms of the series, which are a rational function of the index, can be decomposed into a sum of rational terms
\begin{equation}
 u_k=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\lambda_j}{k+a_j}
\end{equation} 
(we suppose the order of the poles is 1).
When $\left|x\right|<1$, the series
\begin{equation}
 f_j(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k+a_j}=x^{-a_j}\int_0^x \frac{t^{a_j}}{1-t}\,dt+\frac{1}{a_j}
\end{equation} 
This can be verified by developping the $(1-t)^{-1}$ term in the integral.
Then, the series
\begin{align}
 S(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty u_kx^k\\
 &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\lambda_jx^k}{k+a_j}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j\left[x^{-a_j}\int_0^x \frac{t^{a_j}}{1-t}\,dt+\frac{1}{a_j}\right]\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\lambda_j}{a_j}+\int_0^x \frac{\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jx^{-a_j}t^{a_j}}{1-t}\,dt
\end{align}
The proposed series corresponds to $\lim_{x\to1^{-}}S(x)$. Due to the denominator in the integral, in order that this limit exists, the condition 
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j=0
\end{equation} 
must hold. Then
\begin{equation}
 S(1)=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\lambda_j}{a_j}+\int_0^1 \frac{\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jt^{a_j}}{1-t}\,dt
\end{equation} 
The remaining integral can be directly calculated.

In the proposed case, using a CAS,
\begin{align}
 u_k&=\frac{48}{371}\frac{118720 k^2+762311 k+1409424}{(4 k+9) (4 k+11) (4 k+13) (4 k+15) (4 k+17) (4 k+19) (4 k+21) (4 k+23)} \\
 &=-{\frac {181203}{3799040\,k+21844480}}+{\frac {418643}{759808\,k+
3229184}}-{\frac {293677}{759808\,k+2849280}}\\
&\,\quad+{\frac {743573}{3799040
\,k+12346880}}+{\frac {181203}{759808\,k+3988992}}-{\frac {1868267}{
3799040\,k+18045440}}\\
&\,\quad-{\frac {56237}{759808\,k+2089472}}+{\frac {56237
}{3799040\,k+8547840}}
\end{align}
after some calculations, one obtains
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\lambda_j}{a_j}&=\frac{7516928}{124151182155}\\
 \sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jt^{a_j}&=-{\frac {181203}{3799040}{t}^{{\frac{23}{4}}}}+{\frac {418643}{759808}
{t}^{{\frac{17}{4}}}}-{\frac {293677}{759808}{t}^{{\frac{15}{4}}}}+{
\frac {743573}{3799040}{t}^{{\frac{13}{4}}}}\\
&\,\quad+{\frac {181203}{759808}{t
}^{{\frac{21}{4}}}}-{\frac {1868267}{3799040}{t}^{{\frac{19}{4}}}}-{
\frac {56237\,{t}^{11/4}}{759808}}+{\frac {56237\,{t}^{9/4}}{3799040}}\\
&=\frac{1}{3799040} \left( 181203t+56237 \right)t^{9/4}\left( 1-\sqrt{t} \right)^5
\end{align} 
The above function vanishes at $t=1$, as expected. We have to evaluate
\begin{align}
 S(1)&=\frac{7516928}{124151182155}+\frac{1}{3799040} \int_0^1 \frac{\left( 181203t+56237 \right)t^{9/4}\left( 1-\sqrt{t} \right)^5}{1-t}\,dt \\
  &=\frac{7516928}{124151182155} +\frac{1}{949760}\int_0^1\frac{\left( 181203v^4+56237 \right)v^{12}\left( 1-v^2 \right)^5}{1+v^2}\,dv
\end{align}
To evaluate the integral, by devloping the numerator, we have to calculate terms as
\begin{equation}
 I_n=\int_0^1\frac{v^{2n}}{1+v^2}\,dv
\end{equation} 
A recurrence relation can be found easily:
\begin{equation}
 I_n=\frac{1}{2n-1}-I_{n-1}
\end{equation} 
from which we have (with $I_0=\pi/4$)
\begin{equation}
 I_n=(-1)^{n-1}\sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^{p}}{2p+1}+(-1)^n\frac{\pi}{4}
\end{equation} 
After (rather uninteresting) calculations, we get 
\begin{equation}
 \frac{1}{949760}\int_0^1\frac{\left( 181203v^4+56237 \right)v^{12}\left( 1-v^2 \right)^5}{1+v^2}\,dv=\pi-{\frac{780059253811}{248302364310}}
\end{equation} 
Finally
\begin{equation}
 S(1)=\pi-\frac{333}{106}
\end{equation} 
as expected.

Comment: Really really nice job. Very illuminating (+1)

Comment: @clathratus Thanks for this comment!

Comment: This would be almost impossible to do by hand.

Comment: @martycohen I must agree. I think though, given the caliber of the series in question, purely manual calculation is an unreasonable expectation. Fell free to prove me wrong though ;)

Answer (score 8):

This series can be obtained with the same technique used in [A series to prove $\frac{22}{7}-\pi>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1652812/a-series-to-prove-frac227-pi0)

Let us start from series
$$\sum _{k=0}^\infty \frac{960}{(4k+1)(4k+3)(4k+5)(4k+7)(4k+9)(4k+11)}=\pi-\frac{64}{21}$$

to obtain the following truncations:

$$\sum _{k=1}^\infty \frac{960}{(4k+1)(4k+3)(4k+5)(4k+7)(4k+9)(4k+11)}=\pi-\frac{2176}{693}$$ 
$$\sum _{k=2}^\infty \frac{960}{(4k+1)(4k+3)(4k+5)(4k+7)(4k+9)(4k+11)}=\pi-\frac{4288}{1365}$$ 
$$\sum _{k=3}^\infty \frac{960}{(4k+1)(4k+3)(4k+5)(4k+7)(4k+9)(4k+11)}=\pi-\frac{45708032}{14549535}$$

The approximation we are interested in lies between two of these fractions.

$$ \frac{4288}{1365}< \frac{333}{106} < \frac{45708032}{14549535}$$

Therefore, a series for $\pi-\frac{333}{106}$ can be obtained as a mix of the series for $\pi-\frac{4288}{1365}$ and $\pi-\frac{45708032}{14549535}$.

From $$\pi-\frac{333}{106} = a(\pi-\frac{4288}{1365})+b(\pi-\frac{45708032}{14549535})$$

we obtain 
$$a=\frac{56237}{237440}$$
$$b=\frac{181203}{237440}$$

Finally,

$$\pi-\frac{333}{106}=\frac{56237}{237440}(\pi-\frac{4288}{1365})+\frac{181203}{237440}(\pi-\frac{45708032}{14549535})=$$
$$\frac{56237}{237440}\sum _{k=2}^\infty \frac{960}{(4k+1)(4k+3)(4k+5)(4k+7)(4k+9)(4k+11)}+$$
$$\frac{181203}{237440}\sum _{k=3}^\infty \frac{960}{(4k+1)(4k+3)(4k+5)(4k+7)(4k+9)(4k+11)}=$$
$$\frac{56237}{237440}\sum _{k=0}^\infty \frac{960}{(4k+9)(4k+11)(4k+13)(4k+15)(4k+17)(4k+19)}+$$
$$\frac{181203}{237440}\sum _{k=0}^\infty \frac{960}{(4k+13)(4k+15)(4k+17)(4k+19)(4k+21)(4k+23)}=$$
$$\frac{48}{371} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{118720 k^2+762311 k+1409424}{(4 k+9) (4 k+11) (4 k+13) (4 k+15) (4 k+17) (4 k+19) (4 k+21) (4 k+23)}$$

Comment: Very interesting. How do you know the initial series $\pi-64/21$?

Comment: I start from $$\frac{\pi}{8}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(4k+1)(4k+3)}$$ and plug more factors into WolframAlpha.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Comment: This is very very clever... I will re-read your answer more thoroughly when I am a little more awake. It is indeed very short and elegant. (+1)

Comment: Thank you both! You may want to have a look at what FDP managed to get: a linear numerator. 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1656475/a-series-of-positive-terms-to-prove-pi-frac333106
The remaining question is: is there a similar series with constant numerator?

Comment: BTW, don't you think that the inegalities you check are not necessary? In principle, the method could "extrapolate" out of the interval of the two series.

Comment: Yes, but this ensures positive coefficients a and b, which leads to series with all terms positive. This proves directly that pi is larger than the fraction.

Comment: Sorry if this is obvious, but I am a little new to this technique. How exactly does one get the sum for $\pi-64/21$ from $$\pi=8\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{1}{(4k+1)(4k+3)}?$$ I've been trying the truncation trick. Specifically, I noticed that your series for $\pi-64/21$ has six terms in the product, so we must use 3 truncations of the sum $\pi=8\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{1}{(4k+1)(4k+3)}$. These are $S_1=\pi$, $S_2=\pi-8/3$, and $S_3=\pi-8/3-8/35$. Then I used $-\frac1{10}S_1+\frac{3}{5}S_2+\frac{1}{2}S_3=\pi-\frac{64}{21}$ to get...

Comment: ... the series $$\pi-\frac{64}{21}=\frac15\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{1280n^4+6144n^3+9184n^2+3456n-379}{(4n+1)(4n+3)(4n+5)(4n+7)(4n+9)(4n+11)},$$ but this is obviously not what I'm looking for. Any advice?

Comment: Interesting, but this is not how I get it. I try series with this kind of denominators on WolframAlpha and I write down the ones I like for some reason. Here, we have int(21pi)=64, so the series is somehow interesting. Anyway, maybe you can get this one from five pieces, with denominators (4k+1)(4k+3), (4k+3)(4k+5), ... (

Comment: @JaumeOliverLafont thanks. Would you happen to have any resources on these types series identities and the manipulations involved in deriving them?