# Calculating value of $\pi$ independently using integrals.

Tags: definite-integrals, pi

Recently I noticed this integral:

> $$\int_0^1\frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{22}7-\pi\approx0$$

Which is a very interesting result which gives us the value of $\pi\approx\frac{22}7\approx3.142857142$ with 2 decimal places correct.

**Note that actual value of $\pi\approx$3.14159265359**

- I suppose this happens because as $0<x<1$. So $\displaystyle \frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}\ll1$, so integral must approximately be zero.
- Integrating this by hand:
  $$\int_0^1\frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^1\left(x^6-4x^5+5x^4-4x^2+4-\frac{4}{x^2+1}\right)dx$$
  which can be easily calculated, and  the $(x^2+1)^{-1}$ term will make an $\arctan$ term which will generate $\pi$.
- Taking this to the next level I calculated these which all can be done by hand:

> $$\int_0^1\frac{x^8(1-x)^8}{1+x^2}dx=4\pi-\frac{188684}{150115}\approx0\quad:\pi\approx\frac{188684}{4\times150115}=\frac{47171}{15015}\approx3.141591741$$

- 5 decimal places correct.

> $$\int_0^1\frac{x^{12}(1-x)^{12}}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{431302721}{8580495}-16\pi\approx0\quad:\pi\approx\frac{431302721}{16\times8580495}=\frac{431302721}{137287920}\approx3.14159265433$$

- 8 decimal places correct.
- With such an effort(probably using some software) we can go to these:

> $$\int_0^1\frac{x^{8n}(1-x)^{8n}}{1+x^2}dx=A(n)-B(n)\pi\tag{1}$$
>   $$\int_0^1\frac{x^{8n+4}(1-x)^{8n+4}}{1+x^2}dx=C(n)\pi-D(n)\tag{2}$$
>   where $n={0,1,2,3,\ldots}$ and $A,B,C,D$ are functions of n, all of which are always positive.

- And with $n\to\infty$ we'll probably reach exact value of $\pi$

**Results:**

- This type of integrals $(1)$ and $(2)$
  are very close to zero and help finding values of $\pi$
- The no. of correct  decimal places from an AP: $2,5,8,\ldots$
- The coefficient of $\pi$ term alternate as $(-1)^{n/4}4^n$
- Other similar results and any of yours, if you observed.

**Real question:**

- Can anyone put more insight to this as to explain the results?Isn't there any circular reasoning involved?

Comment: Take a look at [this related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1956/11619).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This integral has a series equivalent

$$\frac{22}{7}-\pi=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{240}{(4k+1)(4k+2)(4k+3)(4k+5)(4k+6)(4k+7)}$$

More generally,
$$\sum_{k=m}^\infty \frac{240}{(4k+1)(4k+2)(4k+3)(4k+5)(4k+6)(4k+7)}=\int_0^1 \frac{x^{4m}(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}dx$$

which gives closer rational approximations to $\pi$ by adding more terms of the summation.

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1657416/134791

A similar result is obtained changing the denominator to $\frac{1-x^8}{1-x^2}=1+x^2+x^4+x^6$.

$$ \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3} \int_0^1 \frac{x^4 (1-x)^4} {1+x^2+x^4+x^6} dx = \frac{20 \sqrt{2}}{9}-\pi$$

Other interesting denominators are $1+x+x^2$, $\frac{1-x^6}{1-x^2}$ and $\frac{1-x^{12}}{1-x^2}$, which lead to approximations involving $\sqrt{3}$ and different exponents in the numerator.

Answer (score 2):

Its famous integral :)  I too researched on this  some time before.

I found this, quite useful :
[Integral approximations to
π
with nonnegative
integrands](http://educ.jmu.edu/~lucassk/Papers/more%20on%20pi.pdf).

Comment: While that is a _very_ useful reference, as it stands 1) this is a link-only post, 2) this could just as well have been a comment.

Answer (score 2):

From [wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html) I get this:

Backhouse (1995) used the identity $$\begin{aligned}I_{m, n} &= \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{m}(1 - x)^{n}}{1 + x^{2}}\,dx\\
&= 2^{-(m + n + 1)}\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(m + 1)\Gamma(n + 1)\times{}_{3}F_{2}\left(1, \frac{m + 1}{2}, \frac{m + 2}{2};\frac{m + n + 2}{2}, \frac{m + n + 3}{2}; -1\right)\\
&= a + b\pi + c\log 2\end{aligned}$$ for positive integers $m$ and $n$ and where $a, b$ and $c$ are rational constants to generate a number of formulas for $\pi$. In particular, if $$2m - n \equiv 0\pmod{4}$$ then $c = 0$ (Lucas 2005).

Comment: I suppose $F$ is hypergeometric function and $\Gamma$ is $(n-1)!$?

Comment: @Aditya: yes, but gamma is more than factorial. however, here because of integer argument its just a factorial.