# A series to prove $\frac{22}{7}-\pi>0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, approximation, pi, diophantine-approximation

After T. Piezas answered [Is there a series to show $22\pi^4>2143\,$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649890/is-there-a-series-to-show-22-pi42143) a natural question is

> Is there a series that proves $\frac{22}{7}-\pi>0$?

One such series may be found combining linearly the series that arise from truncating 
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{48}{(4k+3)(4k+5)(4k+7)(4k+9)} = \frac{16}{5}-\pi$$
to two and three terms, namely

$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{48}{(4 k+3) (4 k+5) (4 k+7) (4 k+9)} = \frac{141616}{45045}-\pi$$
and
$$\sum_{k=3}^\infty \frac{48}{(4 k+3) (4 k+5) (4 k+7) (4 k+9)} = \frac{2406464}{765765}-\pi$$
Solving
$$a\left(\frac{141616}{45045}-\pi\right)+b\left(\frac{2406464}{765765}-\pi\right)=\frac{22}{7}-\pi$$
for rational $a,b$ and some algebra manipulation yields the result

> $$\frac{16}{21} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1008 k^2+6952 k+12625}{(4 k+11) (4 k+13) (4 k+15) (4 k+17) (4 k+19) (4 k+21)}=\frac{22}{7}-\pi$$

It is interesting to note that the coefficients needed to multiply the two component series are both positive
$$a=\frac{113}{7·8·9}$$
$$b=\frac{391}{7·8·9}$$

because the truncation points have been chosen so that

$$\frac{2406464}{765765}<\frac{22}{7}<\frac{141616}{45045}$$

This procedure yields a result that proves the claim with no need for further processing, and it is readily seen to prove $\frac{p}{q}-\pi>0$ for all fractions between $\pi$ and $\frac{16}{5}$.

Now, in the light of this equivalent form of Lehmer's formula
$$\pi-3=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{4!}{(4k+1)(4k+2)(4k+4)}$$

one may still ask

> **Q1** Is there a series that proves $\frac{22}{7}-\pi>0$ with constant numerator?
>
> **Q2** Is there a reason why $113$ is both the numerator of the $a$ coefficient and the denominator of the next convergent from above $\frac{355}{113}$?

Edit: A similar series with smaller coefficients may be obtained by applying the method above to
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{960}{(4 k+3) (4 k+5) (4 k+7) (4 k+9) (4 k+11) (4 k+13)} 
&=
\frac{992}{315}-\pi \\
&=
\frac{3·333-7}{3·106-3}-\pi \\
\end{align}
$$
in order to obtain
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{96 (160 k^2+422 k+405)}{(4 k+3) (4 k+5) (4 k+7) (4 k+9) (4 k+11) (4 k+13) (4 k+15) (4 k+17)} = \frac{22}{7}-\pi$$

> **Q3** What is the relationship between $\frac{992}{315}$ and the third convergent to $\pi$ $\frac{333}{106}$?

Comment: Do you have the answer for this question ?

Comment: No, I don't have them.

Comment: @user230452 Now I do.

Comment: If you like this Math.SE question you may also enjoy reading [this](http://mathoverflow.net/q/67384/13917) MO.SE post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Q1**

Evaluating the following series
$$\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{240}{(4k+5)(4k+6)(4k+7)(4k+9)(4k+10)(4k+11)} \\
&=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{4k+5}-\frac{4}{4k+6}+\frac{5}{4k+7}-\frac{5}{4k+9}+\frac{4}{4k+10}-\frac{1}{4k+11}\right) \\
&=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_{0}^1\left(x^{4k+4}-4x^{4k+5}+5x^{4k+6}-5x^{4k+8}+4x^{4k+9}-x^{4k+10}\right)dx \\
&=
\int_{0}^1 x^4\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(x^{4k}-4x^{4k+1}+5x^{4k+2}-5x^{4k+4}+4x^{4k+5}-x^{4k+6}\right)dx \\
&=
\int_{0}^1 x^4\frac{1-4x+5x^2-5x^4+4x^5-x^6}{1-x^4}dx \\
&=
\int_{0}^1 x^4\frac{(1-x^2)(1-x)^4}{(1-x^2)(1+x^2)}dx=\int_{0}^1 \frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{22}{7}-\pi \\
\end{align}$$
shows its connection with Dalzell's integral.

This may be rewritten as
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{240}{(4k+1)(4k+2)(4k+3)(4k+5)(4k+6)(4k+7)}=\frac{22}{7}-\pi$$

which appears in the 2009 document by Peter Bala **New series for old functions** http://oeis.org/A002117/a002117.pdf (formula 5.1)
and shows that $\frac{22}{7}-\pi$ can be obtained by taking one term out of the summation in the series
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{240}{(4k+1)(4k+2)(4k+3)(4k+5)(4k+6)(4k+7)}=\frac{10}{3}-\pi$$

Consecutive truncations  yield the inequality

$$\pi...<\frac{141514}{45045}<\frac{10886}{3465}<\frac{22}{7}<\frac{10}{3}$$

Similar fractions, but now converging to $\pi$ from below, may be obtained from the series

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{240}{(4 k+3) (4 k+4) (4 k+5) (4 k+7) (4 k+8) (4 k+9)} = \pi-\frac{47}{15}$$

This yields

$$\frac{47}{15}<\frac{1979}{630}<\frac{141511}{45045}<\frac{9622853}{3063060}<...\pi$$

(See a similar [inequality for $\log(2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1648983/134791))

**Correspondence between series and integrals**

$$\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{240}{(4k+1)(4k+2)(4k+3)(4k+5)(4k+6)(4k+7)}=\int_0^1 \frac{x^{4n}(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}dx$$

$$\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{240}{(4 k+3) (4 k+4) (4 k+5) (4 k+7) (4 k+8) (4 k+9)}=\int_0^1 \frac{x^{4n+2}(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}dx$$

**Equivalent expressions**

The general term for these series may be written in compact form using factorials, binomial coefficients or the Beta integral $B$ (see this [comment by N. Elkies](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67384/source-and-context-of-frac227-pi-int-01-x-x24-dx-1x2#comment572537_231250)).

$$\begin{align}
\frac{22}{7}-\pi
&=
3840\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(k+2)!(4k)!}{(4k+8)!k!} \\
\\
&=
\frac{4}{21} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\displaystyle{k+2 \choose 2}}{\displaystyle{4k+8\choose 8}} \\
\\
&=
\frac{4}{21} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k+1}{\displaystyle{4k+7\choose 7}} \\
\\
&=
\frac{16}{21} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{B(4k+1,8)}{B(k+1,2)}
\end{align}
$$

**[Interpretation of $\frac{22}{7}-\pi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1662540/interpretation-of-frac227-pi)**

**Similar series and approximations**

If we use the [Pochhammer symbol](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pochhammer.html) to express this series:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{7!(k+1)}{(4k+1)_7}=\frac{7}{4}(10-3\pi)\approx 1$$

we can change the numbers to obtain variants such as

$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{5!(k+1)}{(3k+1)_{5}} = \frac{5}{9}\left(2\sqrt{3}\pi-9\right)\approx 1,
$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{11! (k+1)}{(6 k+1)_{11}} = 231-\frac{4565 \pi}{36 \sqrt{3}}\approx 1$$

and 
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{15!(k+1)}{(8k+1)_{15}}=\frac{15}{8}(1716-7(99\sqrt{2}-62)\pi)\approx 1$$

Given that all three series evaluate to almost 1, the following corresponding approximations are derived

$$\begin{align}
\pi
&=\frac{9\sqrt{3}}{5}+\sqrt{3}\int_0^1\frac{x^3(1-x)^2(1+x)}{1+x+x^2}dx\\
&\approx\frac{9\sqrt{3}}{5} \\
\pi
&=\frac{1656\sqrt{3}}{913}- \frac{6\sqrt{3}}{83}\int_0^1  \frac{x^6(1-x)^8}{1+x^2+x^4} dx\\
&\approx\frac{1656\sqrt{3}}{913} \\
\pi
&=\frac{1838 \left(62 + 99 \sqrt{2}\right)}{118185}-\frac{62+99\sqrt{2}}{15758}\int_0^1 \frac{x^8(1-x)^{12}}{1+x^2+x^4+x^6}dx\\
&\approx
\frac{1838 \left(62 + 99 \sqrt{2}\right)}{118185}
\end{align}$$

which give 1, 5 and 8 correct decimals respectively.

The fraction $\frac{1838}{118185}$ is the eighth convergent of $\frac{\pi}{62+99\sqrt{2}}$

**Another series and integral for $\frac{22}{7}-\pi$**

$$\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{285120}{(4k+2)(4k+3)(4k+5)(4k+6)(4k+7)(4k+9)(4k+10)(4k+11)(4k+13)(4k+14)} \\
&=
\frac{1}{28}\int_{0}^1 \frac{x(1-x)^8(2+7x+2x^2)}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{22}{7}-\pi \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: So based on several series versions already found for 22/7 - Pi, it appears that similar to infinite number of integral expressions (as it was shown by Thomas Baruchel), there are infinite number of series as well.

Comment: You are quite wrong wishing ALL the terms be positive. Anyway your example is nice. Regards.

Comment: @Piquito Reading the proof in reverse shows how the positive integrand naturally leads to all terms positive.

Answer (score 1):

[Proof that $\frac{22}{7}$ exceeds $\pi$.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_22/7_exceeds_%CF%80)

$$0<\int_0^1\frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{22}{7}-\pi$$

Proof-

$$\int_0^1\frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}dx$$

$$=\int_0^1x^6-4x^5+5x^4-4x^2+4-\frac{4}{1+x^2}dx$$

$$=\frac {x^7}{7}+\frac{2x^6}{3}+x^5-\frac{4x^3}{3}+4x-4\tan^{-1}(x)\vert_0^1$$

Now,by applying $\tan^{-1}1=45^\circ=\frac\pi4$ and substituting it in the integral and solving the integral yields $\frac{22}{7}-\pi$

Comment: Why is that integral greater than zero ? Is is just because integral represents an area ? Moreover, what is the usual strategy to evaluate this integral ?

Comment: @tatan: since this does not answer either question, would you please write it as a comment?

Comment: @JaumeOliverLafont Its also a series....

Comment: @user230452 I have added the proof....

Comment: @tatan your answer is about the integral proof for $\frac{22}{7}-\pi>0$, while this question addresses proofs using series with positive terms only.

Comment: @user230452 It's $>0$ because the integrand is always $>0$ in the domain of integration.

Comment: I have no prove of it, but $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{41760+576k}{(4k+3)(4k+5)(4k+7)(4k+9)(4k+11)(4k+13)(4k+15)(4k+17)}=\dfrac{22}{7}-\pi$

Comment: @FDP Great! Your numerator is $288(145+2k)$
WA check
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(k%3D0..inf,(41760%2B576k)%2F((4k%2B3)(4k%2B5)(4k%2B7)(4k%2B9)(4k%2B11)(4k%2B13)(4k%2B15)(4k%2B17)))
Partial fraction expansion and then grouping into Gregory-Leibniz pairs can prove it by hand, if you want to.
Would you write this into an answer? If not, at least as a comment to the question, not to this answer, please.

Comment: @FDP How did you get it? Combining three truncations instead of two? If that is the case, possibly combining four lets impose one more condition, namely, cancelling the $k$ term?

Comment: It seems such equalities aren't rare. I got this one experimenting with lindep function of PARI GP (LLL stuff).

Comment: This is a Riemann integral so it is a limit of series and it is obvious  positive. On the other hand, it is unnecessary  that ALL the termes are positive as Olivert Lafont wishes (he is wrong in this).

Comment: @Piquito Am I correct?

Comment: @tatan: I think implicitly yes. However it would be nice to add the idea of Riemann integrale

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_n$    any series converging to $\pi$ and choose any series converging to $\frac{22}{7}$, for instance $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{15}{22}\right)^n$

No problem to show that
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\left(\frac{15}{22}\right)^n -a_n\right)=\frac{22}{7}-\pi\gt 0 $$

Comment: Does this series have all terms positive?

Comment: From a certain range, yes.

Comment: How can we prove $\frac{22}{7}-\pi>0$ from that series if not all terms are positive?

Comment: Theorem.-Let $a=\sum a_n$ and $b=\sum b_n$ two convergent series. Then , for all pair of constants $\alpha$, $\beta$ the series $\sum(\alpha a_n+\beta b_n)$ converges to $\alpha a+ \beta b$ (Mathematical Analysis, T. M. Apostol). Can you exhibit an example of what you say?

Comment: This proves $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left((\frac{15}{22})^n -a_n\right)=\frac{22}{7}-\pi$$
but not
$$\frac{22}{7}-\pi>0$$

Comment: ► I understand your game now (something like show that 2> 1). Anyway there are countless examples like yours and none for which the result be $\le 0$. I assumed that, since the number $\frac{22}{7}=3.142....$ and $\pi=3.141....$, we have $\sum (a_n-b_n)$ is positive from a certain index n (you can take as the first term of the series the corresponding to this n). I have no desire to continue. I stop here. Regards.