# Why is ${22\over7}-\pi =\int_0^1{(x-x^2)^4\over1+x^2}dx$

Tags: integration, pi

Is this relationship purely an example of a mathematician searching for an equation that satisfies it, or is there a deeper, (possibly geometric), reason?

Comment: See [this paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-32377-0_18) for more examples

Comment: You can find answer for your question here 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_22/7_exceeds_%CF%80

Comment: As far as I know, this type of integral is related to investigating rational approximation of $\pi$, and indeed one of its variants is used for establishing finiteness of the irrationality measure of $\pi$. Perhaps [*this*](http://www.nieuwarchief.nl/serie5/pdf/naw5-2000-01-4-372.pdf) may be a good one to give a read.

Comment: There are integral of that nature with higher exponents that give an even better approximation of pi. I am sure they are on the internet somewhere

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question has been asked before on here...

Comment: @FrankW. I know of a version on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67384/source-and-context-of-frac227-pi-int-01-x-x24-dx-1x2 (this is not to say there is none here; only that I know  that one)

Comment: @FrankW. I have listed a few questions about this integral [here in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/46148/2018/5/13). Maybe somebody can find some other copies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an integral that proves $\pi &gt; 333/106$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956/is-there-an-integral-that-proves-pi-333-106)

Comment: An interpretation: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1662540/interpretation-of-frac227-pi