# Is there an integral for $\pi^4-\frac{2143}{22}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, approximation, pi

In *Ramanujan's Notebooks, Vol 4*, p.48 (and a related one in *Quarterly Journal of Mathematics*, XLV, 1914) there are various approximations, including the close (by just $10^{-7}$),

$$\pi^4 \approx 2^4+3^4+\frac{1}{2+\Big(\frac{2}{3}\Big)^2} = \frac{2143}{22}$$

We can also easily calculate $\pi^3 \approx 31.0062$ and [know that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956/is-there-an-integral-that-proves-pi-333-106),

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{22}{7} - \pi $$

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{x^8(1-x)^8(25+816x^2)}{28\cdot113(1+x^2)} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{355}{113} - \pi $$

> **Q:** Are there then analogous integrals for these early approximations of $\pi^k$,

$$ \int_0^1 f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x = \pi^2 -\frac{1+2\times113}{23} $$

$$ \int_0^1 f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x = \pi^3 - 31 $$

$$ \int_0^1 f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x = \pi^4 -\frac{2143}{22} $$

Comment: Silly answer, if you let $f(x) = \pi^4 - \tfrac{2143}{22}$, then $\int_0^1 f(x) ~ dx $ would be equal to what you want.

Comment: Presumably you want an  integral of  P/Q from A to B where P and Q are polynomials with integer coefficients and A,B are rational, I know that the square of pi comes up in some such integrals that need complex residue theory to evaluate,. e.g. P=1, Q=1/(1+x^4) for x from 0 to infinity.You might try looking at some of these.

Comment: I know that $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\,\frac{t}{\exp(t)-1}\,\text{d}t=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ and $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\,\frac{t^3}{\exp(t)-1}\,\text{d}t=\frac{\pi^4}{15}$.  It is easy to manipulate these two integrals to get something of the forms $\displaystyle\int_0^1\,f(x)\,\text{d}x=\pi^2-\frac{227}{23}$ and $\displaystyle\int_0^1\,f(x)\,\text{d}x=\pi^4-\frac{2143}{22}$.  However, frankly, I don't think that these integrals will be meaningful.

Comment: @Batominovski: Perhaps something more difficult, like  $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} \mathrm{d}x$ where $P(x), Q(x)$ are polynomials with integer coefficients analogous to the examples. Just to see if it can be done.

Comment: Let $\mathbb{A}$ be the field of algebraic numbers.  You question reduces to finding $s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_n\in \mathbb{A}$ and $t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_n\in\mathbb{A}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n\,s_i\ln\left(t_i\right)=R(\pi)$, where $R(x)\in\mathbb{A}[x]$ is of degree at least $2$.  I conjecture that this is impossible.

Comment: $$\pi^2-\frac{355}{36}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{4}{((k+1)(k+2)(k+3))^2}$$
http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1644137/134791

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is yes.  The method is detailed in [the paper by S. K. Lucas](http://www.jstor.org/stable/27642693).  The approximate fractions are obtained from truncating the exact continued fraction of the respected numbers, so the signs are alternating.  We first give a few examples.

## Results

### For $\pi$

The continued fractions are
$3, 22/7, 333/106, 355/113, 103993/33102, \dots$.

\begin{align}
\pi - \frac{333}{106}
&=
\int_0^1 \frac{x^4 \, (1-x)^5 \, \left(74 \, x^2-53 \, x+21\right)}{106 \left(x^2+1\right)} \, dx.
\\
\frac{355}{113} - \pi
&=
\int_0^1 \frac{x^{10} \, (1-x)^8 \, \left(886+95\,x^2\right)}{3164 \left(x^2+1\right)} \, dx.
\end{align}

### For $\pi^2$

The truncated continued fractions are $9, 10, 69/7, 79/8, 227/23, 10748/1089, \dots$,

\begin{align}
\pi^2-\frac{69}{7}
&=
\int_0^1
\frac{4 \, x^{4} \, (1 - x)^3 \left(64 x^2 -39 x + 25\right)}
{13 \, (1 + x^2) }
\log(x^{-1}) \, dx \\
&=
\int_0^1
\frac{24 \, x^{6} \, (1 - x)^2 \left(119 - 72 \, x^2\right)}
{191 \, (1 + x^2) }
\log(x^{-1}) \, dx.
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\frac{79}{8} - \pi^2
&=
\int_0^1
\frac{4 \, x^6 \, (1-x)^3 (49 - 51 x + 100 x^2)}
{17 \, (1 + x^2) }
\log(x^{-1}) \, dx \\
&=
\int_0^1
\frac{4 \, x^3 \, (1-x)^4 (25 + 2254 x^2)}
{743 \, (1 + x^2) }
\log(x^{-1}) \, dx \\
&=
\int_0^1
\frac{
24 \, x^5 \, (1-x)^2 \left[37 \, (x^2 + 1) - 73 \, x\right]
}
{ 73 \, (1 + x^2) }
\log(x^{-1}) \, dx
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\pi^2-\frac{227}{23}
&=
\int_0^1
\frac{4 \, x^{19} \, (1 - x)^4 \left(61847 x^2+87524\right)}
{8559 \, (1 + x^2) }
\log(x^{-1}) \, dx.
\end{align}

### For $\pi^3$

The truncated continued fractions are
$31, 4930/159, 14821/478, \dots$.

\begin{align}
\pi^3-31
&=
\int_0^1
\frac{8 \, x^5 \, (1-x)^2 \, \left(324889-120736 \, x^2\right)}
{445625 \, (1 + x^2) }
\log^2 x \, dx\\
\frac{4930}{159}-\pi^3
&=
\int_0^1
\frac{4 \, x^{10} \, (1-x)^4 \, \left(695774836+470936528857 \, x^2\right)}
{470240754021 \, (1 + x^2) }
\log^2 x \, dx.
\end{align}

### For $\pi^4$

The truncated continued fractions are
$97, 195/2, 487/5, 1656/17, 2143/22, \dots$.

\begin{align}
\pi^4-97
&=
\int_0^1
\frac{240 \, x^{4} \, (1 - x)^{2} \,\left(3522267 x^2+1681375\right) }
{3221561 \, (1 + x^2) }
\log^3(x^{-1}) \, dx
\\
\frac{195}{2}-\pi^4
&=
\int_0^1
\frac{192 \, x^{6} \, (1 - x)^{2} \, \left(5657688 x^2+3056473\right) }
{3641701 \, (1 + x^2) }
\log^3(x^{-1}) \, dx.
\\
\pi^4-\frac{487}{5}
&=
\int_0^1
\frac{15 \, x^{8} \, (1 - x)^{2} \, \left(3293858975 x^2+746556831\right) }
{278611172 \, (1 + x^2) }
\log^3(x^{-1}) \, dx.
\\
\frac{1656}{17}-\pi^4
&=
\int_0^1
\frac{480 \, x^{7} \, (1 - x)^{4} \, \left(8555775811 x^2+2883779820\right) }
{39703971937 \, (1 + x^2) }
\log^3(x^{-1}) \, dx.
\\
\pi^4-\frac{2143}{22}
&=
\int_0^1
\frac{480 \, x^{31} \, (1 - x)^{4} \, \left(4071997316165706379 x^2+175446796437023645180\right) }
{1199623593846005571607 \, (1 + x^2) }
\log^3(x^{-1}) \, dx.
\end{align}

### Method

The idea is simple.
We basically combine the following identities.

(1)
\begin{align}
\int_0^1
\log^{s-1}\left( x^{-1} \right) x^k \, dx
= \frac{(s-1)!}{(k+1)^s}.
\end{align}

For an even $s$

(2a)
\begin{align}
\int_0^1
\frac{ \log^{s-1}(x^{-1}) \, x }{1+x^2} \, dx
&=2^{-s} \int_0^\infty
\frac{ t^{s-1} }{ e^t + 1 } \, dt \\
&=2^{-s} \int_0^\infty
t^{s-1} \left( e^{-t} - e^{-2\,t} + e^{-3t} - \cdots \right) \, dt \\
&= \frac{ (s-1)! \, (2^s - 2)}{4^s} \zeta(s) \\
&=
\frac{ (1-2^{1-s}) \, |B_s| }{2 \, s} \, \pi^s.
\end{align}
where $\zeta(s)$ is the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function),
$B_s$ is the [Bernoulli number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number), which is rational.
The last step is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_Riemann_zeta_function#Even_positive_integers).

Similarly, for an odd $s$,

(2b)
\begin{align}
\int_0^1
\frac{ \log^{s-1}(x^{-1}) }{1+x^2} \, dx
&=\int_0^\infty
\frac{ t^{s-1} \, e^{-t} }{ e^{-2t} + 1 } \, dt \\
&=\int_0^\infty
t^{s-1} \left( e^{-t} - e^{-3\,t} + e^{-5\,t} -\cdots \right) \, dt \\
&= (s-1)! \, \left(1-\frac{1}{3^s}+\frac{1}{5^s}-\cdots \right) \\
&=
(s-1)! \, \beta(s) = \frac{|E_{s-1}|}{2^{s+1}} \, \pi^s,
\end{align}
where
$E_s$ is the [Euler number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_number),
which is also rational.

This means
\begin{align}
\frac{\pi}{4}
&=
\int_0^1
\frac{ 1 }{1+x^2} \, dx, \\
\frac{\pi^2}{48}
&=
\int_0^1
\frac{\log\left( x^{-1} \right) x}{1+x^2} \, dx\\
\frac{\pi^3}{16}
&=
\int_0^1
\frac{\log^2\left( x^{-1} \right) }{1+x^2} \, dx\\
\frac{7\,\pi^4}{192}
&=
\int_0^1
\frac{\log^3\left( x^{-1} \right) x}{1+x^2} \, dx.
\end{align}

Now suppose we have a polynomial $P(x) = Q(x)(1 + x^2) + R(x)$,
and we want
$$
\int_0^1
\frac{ \log^s(x^{-1}) \, P(x) } { 1 + x^2 }
\, dx
= \pi^s - A,
$$
where $A$ is an approximation of $\pi^s$ (we have assumed the possible sign, the case of negative sign is similar).  To satisfy this equation, we demand,

\begin{align}
\int_0^1
\frac{ \log^s(x^{-1}) \, R(x) } { 1 + x^2 }
\, dx
&= \pi^s \\
\int_0^1
\log^s(x^{-1}) \, Q(x)
\, dx
&= - A,
\end{align}

This requires
\begin{align}
R(x)
&=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{ 2^{s+1} } { |E_{s-1}|}
     & \mathrm{for\; odd\;} s \\
\dfrac{ 2 \, s } { (1-2^{1-s}) \, |B_s| } x
     & \mathrm{for\; even\;} s
\end{cases}
\\
\sum_{n=0} \frac{ (s-1)! }{(n+1)^s} q_n &= -A,
\end{align}
where
$Q(x) = \sum_{n=0} q_n \, x^n$.

Using these to rules to design $P(x)$, we get the above formulas.  Particularly, we studied the form
\begin{align}
P(x)
=
x^u \,(1-x)^v (a \, x^2 + b \, x + c).
\end{align}

For a particular set of $u$ and $v$, the constraint for $R(x)$ determines two parameters, say $b$ and $c$. The constraint for $A$ determines $a$.  We then check if $a \, x^2 + b \, x  + c$ is nonnegative definite.  We then vary $u$ and $v$ to seek a simple combination of $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Comment: Maybe you'd be interested in this [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649890/is-there-a-series-to-show-22-pi42143)?

Comment: Mmm...has someone thought about using these ideas to give an alternative proof $\pi^s$ is irrational for positive $s$? It would be quite pointless since we already know $\pi$ is transcendental. That said, I think another proof using Beukers'-like methods would be a fun endeavor.