# A series related to $\pi\approx 2\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation, pi

This question follows a suggestion by Tito Piezas in [Is there an integral or series for $\frac{\pi}{3}-1-\frac{1}{15\sqrt{2}}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1623368/is-there-an-integral-or-series-for-frac-pi3-1-frac115-sqrt2)

Q: Is there a series by Ramanujan that justifies the approximation $\pi\approx2\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}?$

Comment: Assuming facts not in evidence. Where does it say that there is a series of Ramanujan that justifies that approximation?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: There is in fact an affirmative answer. The question is just to highlight that _sometimes_ there is a reason why simple expressions are relatively close to $\pi$. I'll need time to type the answer.

Comment: I would appreciate if one of moderators would convert this to a comment. Perhaps the original question could be expanded and other relatively simple $\pi$ approximations should be considered? For example, few years ago I found that $$\pi \approx \sqrt{4\cdot e^{1} - 1}.$$

Comment: Eliminating $\pi$ between both approximations, one gets
$$e\approx\frac{5}{4}+\sqrt{2}$$,
with an error about 2%

Yours gives
$$\frac{\sqrt{4e-1}}{\pi}=1.000178...$$

Comment: @Alex: Sorry, but I don't think I'll be able to answer it as a separate question. I looked at my notes and it is harder to find a connection, even if one uses formulas for $\frac{1}{\pi^2}$.

Comment: @Alex $$\pi=\color{green}3.\color{green}1\color{green}4\color{green}1\color{green}5 \color{green}9 \color{green}2\ 65...$$
$$\sqrt{4e-1}=\color{green}3.\color{green}1\color{green}4\ 2 \color{green}1\color{green}5 \color{green} \ 32 \color{green}9\color{green}2\ 5...$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer needs some context.

**Part I.** One may ask why,

$$\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1103}{99^2} \approx 10^{-9}\tag1$$

is such a good approximation? In fact, the [convergents](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5BFromContinuedFraction%5BContinuedFraction%5B1%2F(2Pi*Sqrt%5B2%5D),%20n%5D%5D,%20%7Bn,%2010%7D%5D) of the continued fraction of $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{2}}$ start as,

$$0,\;\frac{1}{8},\;\color{brown}{\frac{1}{3^2}},\;\frac{8}{71},\;\frac{9}{80},\dots\color{brown}{\frac{1103}{99^2}},\dots$$

and it turns out using the 3rd and 9th convergents,

$$\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{3^2} = 16\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(4k)!}{k!^4} \frac{1+10k}{(12^4)^{k+1/2}}$$

$$\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1103}{99^2} = 16\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(4k)!}{k!^4} \frac{1103+26390k}{(396^4)^{k+1/2}}\tag2$$

so truncating $(2)$ "explains" the approximation $(1)$.

**Part II.** The OP's post originated with the observation that,

$$\frac{\pi}{3} -\Big(1+\frac{1}{15\sqrt{2}}\Big) \approx 10^{-5}\tag3$$

The convergents of the continued fraction of $\displaystyle\sqrt{2}\big(\frac{\pi}{3}-1\big)$ are,

$$0,\;\frac{1}{14},\;\color{brown}{\frac{1}{15}},\;\frac{55}{824},\dots$$

As there are dozens and dozens of [Ramanujan-Sato pi formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Sato_series) that use $\sqrt{2}$, it is possible (though not certain) there is one that is directly responsible $(3)$.

**Part III.** Finally, the question. The modest approximation,

$$\pi \approx 2\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}\tag4$$

has an explanation as it is the [first term](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=RootReduce%5B1%2FSum%5B(-1)%5En%20(2n)!%5E3%2Fn!%5E6%20(16(8%2B5Sqrt%5B2%5D)n%2B8(2%2BSqrt%5B2%5D))%2F(2%5E9(1%2BSqrt(2))%5E3)%5E(n%2B1%2F2),%7Bn,0,0%7D%5D%5D) (after some manipulation) of the Ramanujan-type formula,

$$\frac{1}{\pi}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{(2n)!^3}{n!^6} \frac{16(8+5\sqrt{2})n+8(2+\sqrt{2})}{(C)^{n+1/2}},\quad C = 2^9(1+\sqrt{2})^3\tag5$$

And there are *many* other similar ones.

Comment: The coincidence between your unnumbered $\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{2}}\approx \frac{1}{9}$ and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1623368/is-there-an-integral-or-series-for-frac-pi3-1-frac115-sqrt2#comment3321177_1625142
suggests the additional question whether Ramanujan's series may be obtained from $\left(1+x\right)^\frac{1}{2}asin(\frac{x}{2})$

Comment: A "Ramanujan-type" formula isn't the same as a series "by Ramanujan", so this doesn't answer the question that was asked. Don't get me wrong – it's very nice mathematics – it's just not an answer to the question as asked.

Comment: @TitoP Lovely stuff! +1

Comment: @Bacon: Thanks. You'd like formula $(2)$ even more if you find out it is [connected](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14115/motivation-for-ramanujans-mysterious-pi-formula?rq=1) to the _Pell equation_ $x^2-29y^2 = 1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson:  In his 1914 paper, Ramanujan gave 17 formulas for four kinds of families. You're right, the _particular formula_ using $1+\sqrt{2}$ isn't explicitly there, but the _general series_ $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\pi}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n)!^3}{n!^6} \frac{An+B}{C^{n+1/2}}$ is by Ramanujan. :)

Comment: Why $\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{2}}$ is so close to the fifth convergent $\frac{9}{80} $ is explained by
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{160}{(8k+5)(8k+6)(8k+7)(8k+9)(8k+10)(8k+11)} =\frac{20}{9}-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$$