# An integral for $\frac{9801}{2206\sqrt{2}}-\pi$

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals, pi, diophantine-approximation

From integrals

$$\pi=\frac{24\sqrt{2}}{11} + \frac{8}{11} \int_0^1 \frac{x (1 - x)^2(1 + 2 \sqrt{2} x^4)}{1 + x^2 + x^4 + x^6} dx$$

and

$$\pi=\frac{20\sqrt{2}}{9} - \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3} \int_0^1 \frac{x^4(1 - x)^4}{1 + x^2 + x^4 + x^6} dx$$

the following linear combination for [Ramanujan's approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/908535/ramanujans-approximation-for-pi) $\pi\approx\frac{9801}{2206\sqrt{2}}$  is obtained:

$$\pi=\frac{9801}{2206\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{8824}\int_0^1 \frac{x (1 - x)^2 (124 (1 + 2 \sqrt{2} x^4) - 5769 \sqrt{2} x^3 (1 - x)^2)}{1 + x^2 + x^4 + x^6} dx$$

This integrand is small but has sign changes in $\left(0,1\right)$, so it does not provide a direct proof that $\pi<\frac{9801}{2206\sqrt{2}}$ such as [Dalzell integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1662540/interpretation-of-frac227-pi) for $\pi<\frac{22}{7}$.

$$\pi = \frac{22}{7}-\int_0^1 \frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}dx$$

> **Is there an integral for $\frac{9801}{2206\sqrt{2}}-\pi$ with positive integrand?**

Related questions

[Why some curious almost-identities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664175/why-some-curious-almost-identities)

[Is there an integral that proves $\pi > 333/106$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956/is-there-an-integral-that-proves-pi-333-106)

[Is there an integral or series for $\frac{\pi}{3}-1-\frac{1}{15\sqrt{2}}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1623368/is-there-an-integral-or-series-for-frac-pi3-1-frac115-sqrt2)

[An integral for $2\pi+e-9$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1711437/an-integral-for-2-pie-9)

Answer (score 3):

HINT: write your Integrand in the form
$$2\,\sqrt {2}x-4\,\sqrt {2}+{\frac {2\,\sqrt {2}+1}{{x}^{2}+1}}+{\frac 
{2\,{x}^{2}\sqrt {2}-2\,\sqrt {2}x-{x}^{2}+2\,\sqrt {2}+x-1}{{x}^{4}+1
}}
$$

Comment: I don't understand how this makes the integrand positive. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: you must make a partial fraction decomposition and this is the result

Comment: The two main components are
$$-\frac{1}{8824}\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{2} \left(29341 x^4 + (62 \sqrt{2} - 23324) x^3 + (35110 - 124 \sqrt{2}) x^2 + (62 \sqrt{2} - 23324) x + 29341\right)}{x^6 + x^4 + x^2 + 1} dx = -\pi $$
with positive integrand
and 

$$-\frac{1}{8824} \int_0^1 \sqrt{2}(-29341 + 23324 x - 5769 x^2) dx = \frac{9801}{2206\sqrt{2}}$$

with negative integrand in $(0,1)$. I understand the problem comes when adding up, because the absolute value of the positive one is not always larger than the negative...

Comment: (The integrand in the answer is the one from first integral
$$\pi\approx \frac{24\sqrt{2}}{11}$$
)
I am sorry not to see the solution from the hint only yet, maybe after sleeping...

Comment: The partial fraction decomposition of the first two integrals is:

$$\pi=\frac{24\sqrt{2}}{11} + \frac{4\sqrt{2}}{11} \int_0^1 \left(4 (x - 2) + \frac{4 + \sqrt{2}}{1 + x^2} + \frac{(4 - \sqrt{2})(x^2 - x + 1)}{1 + x^4}\right) dx$$

$$\pi=\frac{20\sqrt{2}}{9} - \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3} \int_0^1 \left(x^2 - 4 x + 5 -\frac{2}{1 + x^2} - \frac{3(x^2 - \frac{4}{3}x + 1)}{1 + x^4}\right) dx$$

Comment: The integrals involving $\pi$ are:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = 2\int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+x^4}dx = \frac{\pi}{4}$$
$$\sqrt{2}\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \int_0^1 \frac{1+x^2}{1+x^4}dx=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}$$